# How to use showAllTooltips and mode with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Is it possible to use `showAllTooltips: true` and `mode: 'index'`?

I have this:

```
function pintar_charts(type, type2, type3, item, titulo, titulo2, titulo3, cabeceras, data, data2, data3, color, color2, color3) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById(item);
  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: type,
    data: {
      labels: cabeceras,
      datasets: [{
          type: 'line',
          label: titulo,
          lineTension: 0,
          borderColor: window.chartColors.orange,
          backgroundColor: window.chartColors.orange,
          borderWidth: 3,
          responsive: false,
          data: data,
          fill: false
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          label: titulo2,
          lineTension: 0,
          borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
          backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
          borderWidth: 3,
          responsive: false,
          data: data2,
          fill: false
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          label: titulo3,
          lineTension: 0,
          borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
          backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
          borderWidth: 3,
          responsive: false,
          data: data3,
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      //showAllTooltips: true,
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return tooltipItem.yLabel;
          },
          title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I would like everyone to show

[image: I would like everyone to show]

Comment: Can you post your code in your question plz?

Comment: Please replace the image of your code with a formatted version of your code.

Comment: Ok @KeyMaker00  I did do